# returning image/jpeg as arraybuffer or blob

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

I am currently making a call to my api which returns an image as an `image/jpeg`. My issue is the when calling the url through javascript angular `.factory` resource I am getting my array buffer as empty `{}`. Also, the bytes length is 0. If I make the call to the api url with response type '' or 'text' I do see value of multiple types. What am I missing here? Thank you for your help!

#### JS:

```
.factory("Img", function($resource) {
    return $resource("http://mypathTo/image/:id", {
      id: "@id"
    }, {
      responseType: '' //arraybuffer return empty
    });
  });
```

#### app.controller //code

```
    $scope.getImage = function(productid) {
      console.log(productid);
      par = {id: [productid]};
      Img.getImage(par).$promise.then(
        function(data){
          console.log("success:" + data); //I am able to see bytes when coming back as text but not with arraybuffer as data.bytelength = 0
          scope.productionPicturePath = data;
          return data;
        },
        function(data){
          console.log("error" + data);
        }
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: The [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) service can only return JavaScript objects or arrays depending on `isArray`. To get exotic objects such as [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) or [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), use the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: You have to set other options like `transformResponse `

Comment: @georgeawg thank you for your response i was actually able to implement this and received a response with something! thank you!

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for your response, what would transformresponse do?

Comment: Read the docs in link @george supplied. Default is it parses response from json to object/array which definitely is not what you are working with

Comment: Show us a sample of the response that you are getting with the default responseType.

Comment: I added the following: $http.get('mypathtoimage', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
   .then(function successCallback(response) {

Comment: i seem to be getting an array response now! my image however is still not loading properly, should i convert the array buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) service can only return JavaScript objects or arrays depending on `isArray`. To get exotic objects such as [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) or [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), use the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http).

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/dw6jfoNZQFi4EFsznz0D?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope,$http) {
    var vm = $scope;
    var url="//i.imgur.com/fHyEMsl.jpg";

    var config = { responseType: 'blob' };
    $http.get(url,config)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("OK");
        //console.log(response.data);
        vm.blob = response.data;
        vm.dataURL = URL.createObjectURL(vm.blob);
        console.log(vm.dataURL);
    }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        throw response;
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
      BLOB type {{blob.type}}<br>
      BLOB size {{blob.size}}<br>
    <img ng-src="{{dataURL}}" height="100" />
  </body>
```

Comment: this did it thank you for your help and demo it helped a ton!